# API Body convert and configure to a CSV in JMeter

Tags: json, csv, jmeter

In my system, I need to analyze the performance of loading bulk site list (500 sites). What columns should I use for CSV and how do I configure the CSV with JMeter?

HTTP Request - Body Data:

```json
{
"data":{
    "pagination":{"page":1,"limit":50},
    "requestId":1707548296789,
    "filter":{
        "requiredColumns":["id","name","clientId"],
        "client":["7309d8c6-f3eb-42f4-bc90-d314907ff71d"],
        "search":""
            },
    "sort":{
        "column":"name",
        "direction":"asc"
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Database>Site table has "id","name","clientId" columns and one `clientId` has multiple sites.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need CSV file at all.

- `1707548296789` parameter looks like an [Unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) to me so you can replace it with JMeter's [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time)
- `7309d8c6-f3eb-42f4-bc90-d314907ff71d` is a [GUID](https://www.techtarget.com/searchwindowsserver/definition/GUID-global-unique-identifier)-like structure hence it can be replaced with JMeter's [__UUID() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__UUID)

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions)